# How to profile Java loaded into an Oracle DB?

Tags: java, oracle, profiling

We have to support an application written in PL/SQL with pieces of it written in Java and loaded into an Oracle DB as compiled classes. These Java classes access the same DB and execute additional queries there.

I've been using DBMS_HPROF to locate bottlenecks in the code and one of the packages spends at least half of the time inside a call to a Java function. This call is completely opaque to the PLSQL profiler, so I do not know if it's the Java code that is slow or it's the SQL code that is executed by Java that is slow. How can I profile this function to determine which statement takes the most time?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Can you run your java code externally as a application and profile that?  Or modify the java proc to write timing details to a file or table,